# Linear Instability vs. Nonlinear Stability

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, stability-in-odes, linearization

I have an N-body system that I can simulate directly. For certain initial conditions, this system is unstable to a buckling behavior (exponential growth in an angle), and for others it's stable (oscillations). I've built a linearized model (Taylor series expansion) for the system of 2N coupled ODEs with numerically calculated coefficients. Using standard eigendecomposition methods I can get a spectrum of the modes for the linearized model.

However, I find that a system I know is stable when directly integrated has unstable linear modes within it. Could this make sense, or is it likely that I've made a mistake somewhere in the construction and calculate of my linearized ODE?

Comment: You can't have unstable linear modes around an equilibrium while the full system is stable. You can have that when the full system is unstable but the perturbations send you to a limit cycle that is not "close" to the equilibrium. This might look like stability in your simulations (because the definition of "close" in your setting might be counterintuitively stringent), but it isn't.

Comment: Good to know. I'm pretty sure the full system is stable. We get very clear oscillations around the equilibrium. It's much more likely that there is a problem in my linearized equations.

Comment: Does the distance of the oscillations from the equilibrium depend on how close you start to the equilibrium? It should if the system is actually stable.

Comment: I'm not sure; I would have to look into that. One problem is the linearized system ignores certain physics present in the real system. There is a relaxation process not included within the linear model that rapidly "puffs up" the angles when directly integrated. If I start very close to the equilibrium, this relaxation process will quickly spread the angles out around that equilibrium. I could look at individual particles as some will start closer to the equilibrium than others.